# ssis dynamically truncate table failed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to have a ssis package that would check the folder (and all of its subfolders) and import only files that match the predefined criteria. Depends on what the file name is, it will import into a certain database (all reside in the same sql server). 
The process works like this:
1. check the matching files
2. for each matching file, parse the file's name to get information that determines where the file will be imported to
3. truncate the table that the file in the previous step will be loaded to
4. import the file (in Data Flow Task).

So far i got step 1 and 2 working, and the sql statement to truncate table populate as expected. I run this sql statement manually in ssms and it works.

But i can't pass step 3, got an error below:

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Truncate table, Execute SQL Task: Executing the
>   query "set nocount on; truncate table [db1].[DBO].[TBL_B..." failed
>   with the following error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly. Task failed: Truncate table

Attached are the setting of the package. What am i missing?

[image: package setup]

[image: error]

Comment: "Parameter name is unrecognized". Make sure that your SQL task isn't set up to expect parameters. Also dump out the runtime value of your SSIS vairable `sqlTruncteStatement`. It sounds like you might have a parameter placeholder in there when you shouldn't, especially if it is driven from a filename and a bunch of string functions.

Comment: @ElectricLlama, what do you mean by "Also dump out the runtime value of your SSIS vairable sqlTruncteStatement"?

Comment: I assume from the info you posted you are dynamically building the Truncate SQL to execute using expressions. This SQL is raising an error. So inspect and post the contents of the `sqlTruncateStatement` that has been generated by your code. If I look really hard at your screenshot I can see it might be something like `set nocount on; truncate table`. So now inspect the whole thing, given that it is raising this error. There might be a parameter placeholder in there, or you might have incorrectly specificed that your SQL has parameters. These are all unknowns to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify parameter by giving ParameterName as "0".

And since there will be no resultset to the truncate query, specify ResultSet as None.